# simple scroll menu jquery

Tags: jquery, function, call

I'm trying to make a simple function with JQuery that let's me make a menu that scrolls down to the correct segment of the page. got the scroll part down, but i'm trying to make it into a function to use less code. this is what i have right now. instead of making 6 functions i just wanna call 1 function 6 times. pretty new to javascript and JQuery so please excuse me if i'm being a dumbass

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#seg2').click(function(){
  $.fn.gaNaarPagina(2);
 });


 $.fn.gaNaarPagina = function(number) { 
     var scrollLink = '#segment' + number;

     $('html, body').animate({
                ScrollTop: $(scrollLink).offset().top}, 800);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like CSS properties in JavaScript, the `scrollTop` property is written in Camel Case (not *Pascal case*) The only difference being the first letter, which in camelCase, is a lower-case letter.

If you switch `ScrollTop` with `scrollTop` your code works as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#seg2').click(function () {
        $.fn.gaNaarPagina(2);
    });

    $.fn.gaNaarPagina = function (number) {
        var scrollLink = '#segment' + number;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollLink).offset().top
//     Here ^
        }, 800);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cb3zkh5/3/)